# Server Execution Failed

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I want to open a file in windows explorer on button click.I have a textbox which will have exact location of the file and on button click, that file should get opened in windows explorer. As of now, that file is present on my desktop and not on any remote desktop. 
But, when I tried to open it by using Process. Start, its giving me "Server Execution Failed".
My machine is windows server 2012 R2. This is my piece of code.

```
try
{
    Process.Start("file:\\F:\\deeps");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    TextBox1.Text= ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the file should be opened using Notepad, then please replace this:

```
Process.Start("file:\\F:\\deeps");
```

with this:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"F:\deeps\MyFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to open the folder in the windows explorer only

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your PC than

```
 Process.Start(@"F:\deeps");
```

If it is on server than file:\F:\deeps never gonna work it looks like a mapped address , Try proper address with server ip

```
\\12.12.12.12\Folder_Name
```

> \12.12.12.12 is a dummy IP here

Comment: I tried like \\my _IP_address\\F:\\deeps then it is giving me this error: the system cannot find the file specified. Please help me with this

Comment: @DeepanshiBansal , are you using your external ip ? what is the complete address now ?

Comment: and as of now I am using my local Sharepoint to open the the local file.

Comment: what is the final address ?

Comment: My complete IP address is 172.21.67.133 and in that server machine I am trying to access its local folder

Comment: I have tried the same piece of code in console application, its working as expected.